# Display usernames from JSON response

Tags: php, json, api, curl

i'm trying to display a list of all the Usernames from this JSON response through the enjin API but i am getting this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Code

```
<?php

$s = curl_init();
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://oceanix.enjin.com/api/get-users');

$output = curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);

$decodedJson = json_decode($output);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>username</th>
    </tr>
<?php

    foreach ($decodedJson as $username) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $username->username; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}?>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: print $output without decoding it here please.

Comment: "340341:{"username":"Nord","forum_post_count":"0","forum_votes":"0","forum_up_votes":"0","forum_down_votes":"0","lastseen":"1357188768","datejoined":"1357188768"},

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. Could you copy and paste the whole output into the question *body*? Could you post the contents of `$decodedJson` using something like `var_dump()` as well?

Comment: Surround your input JSON with { and } before decoding it.  Also, `var_dump( $decodedJson )` -- it's probably NULL.

Comment: @J.D.Pace The JSON was already surrounded properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set it up so it goes in to the variable, but rather gets sent to the output stream.

Add:

```
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Before you call `curl_exec()` so that it gets put in to your variable. See [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Full code that works:

```
<?php

$s = curl_init();
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://oceanix.enjin.com/api/get-users');
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);

$decodedJson = json_decode($output);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>username</th>
    </tr>
<?php

    foreach ($decodedJson as $username) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $username->username; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its not displaying the response now, but i'm still getting this error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" even without decoding as @imsiso suggested.

Comment: @user2273278 I edited in the full code that I used to test it, and it outputs as expected for me.

Comment: @user2273278 no problem ^^